# Matlab - fprintf precision format issues

Tags: matlab, printf

I'm stuck trying to save in a text file certain values with a determined format using MATLAB. For example, I need to store the number 85 as .85E+2 (in fact .85D+2, RINEX format). But I'm only capable to obtain 8.5E+1.

So, how could I do to store the values as .XXXE+n?

```
fileID = fopen('Rinexn.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,' %0.13e', eph.IODE_sf3);
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: Where does RINEX put the sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
num = 85;
pow = floor(log10(abs(num)))+1;
sprintf('%.3fE%+d', num/10^pow, pow)
```

or in your case:

```
pow = floor(log10(abs(eph.IODE_sf3)))+1;
fprintf(fileID,'%.3fE%+d', eph.IODE_sf3/10^pow, pow );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on rahnema1's answer, but a more conformant to the format specified in the question (exactly 3 significant digits, no leading zero, `D` as exponentiation character):

```
signs = {'+' '-'};
pow   = floor(log10(abs(N))) + 1;
fprintf(fileID,...
        '%s.%dD%+d\n', ...
         signs{(sign(N) < 0) + 1}, ...
         round(abs(N)/10^(pow-3)),...
         pow);
```

Where `N` is your number. If you don't want an explicit `+` for positive values, remove the `+` from the cell:

```
signs = {' ' '-'};
```

For efficient/convenient vectorization (`N` is a vector):

```
Ns = [signs((sign(N) < 0) + 1)
      num2cell(round(abs(N(:).') ./ 10.^(pow(:).'-3)))
      num2cell(pow(:)')];

fprintf(fileID,...
        '%s.%dD%+d\n', ...
         Ns{:});
```